# Rename outfile with date in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, csv, export, file-io

How can i rename the filename with a concat function ?
i want my filename with a date,, can anyone help me on this.

```
SET @OUTFILE = CONCAT( CONCAT('/xampp/htdocs/mysite/reports-', NOW()), '.csv');


SELECT * FROM `tbl_user` INTO OUTFILE  @OUTFILE FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

Comment: what is the problem with your query

Comment: i always get this error : #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@OUTFILE

Comment: actually im not so familiar in concatination in mysql, anyway i just want my filename to be dynamic, so everytime i run this query it gives me a unique filename with a date ;(

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you can do something [like](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=13870):

```
SET @sql_text = 
   CONCAT (
       "SELECT * FROM `tbl_user` into outfile '/xampp/htdocs/mysite/reports-"
       , DATE_FORMAT( NOW(), '%Y%m%d')
       , ".csv'"
    );

PREPARE s1 FROM @sql_text;
EXECUTE s1;
DROP PREPARE s1;
```

Comment: if its help upvote and set as on V sign to set that is the correct answer

Answer (score 1):

You should use [prepared statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html). Build a query string, then execute it.